# Is there an Azure CLI command for getting Health Check status from Function App?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cli

I've created a Function App, and everything seems to be running fine. In the Azure Portal, Function App Overview I can see that the Health Check is "100.00% (Healthy 2 / Degraded 0)", and on the Health Check page of the Function App I can see that it's enabled and the endpoint is "api/health".

Is there a way to get the "100% (Healthy 2 / Degraded 0)" through an Azure CLI command. It looks like `az functionapp list` only gives me the `siteConfig.healthCheckPath` value and that's not what I need.

[image]

Comment: what do you think about using `curl` with the `siteConfig.healthCheckPath` value?

Comment: Doing a `curl` to the heatlhCheckPath might be impossible (could be that the healthCheckPath is locked behind network restrictions) or in the case of multiple running instances misleading as you would not get the status of each running instance of the function app, but you would get the result for whichever instance the load balancer directs you to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fetch the values of Health Check Status metric by using the Azure CLI command `az monitor metrics list` as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/metrics?view=azure-cli-latest#az-monitor-metrics-list.

Example:
`az monitor metrics list --resource myresource --resource-group myresourcegroup --resource-type "Microsoft.Web/sites" --metric "HealthCheckStatus" --interval 5m`

Note that the --interval property is important as health checks do not support the default 1m interval used by `az monitor metrics list`